# JWT token creating throws error 500 when hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, jwt

Im currently writing a webshop in angular + asp.net core where I use jwt token authentication. Everything works perfectly until the website is hosted on the internet. After that it throws an internal server error when the server is trying to generate the token. It works perfectly fine when running on localhost or iis.

```
//program.cs

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x => { x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; }).AddJwtBearer(x => {

    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };

});

//this method creates the token in the controller
private string createJwtToken(Users user)
        {
            var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]);
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)

            });
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = identity,
                SigningCredentials = credentials,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20)
            };
            var token = jwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
```

I tried changing the issuer and the audience, suspected a no origin allowed error and added cors but nothing helped.

Comment: Check the server logs, include more information about the error, otherwise there's little chance you will get useful feedback here

Comment: One problem I see here is that you use `Jwt:Issuer` also for the `Audience` property. You might want to use another value. But then again... it's hard to imagine what could be the issue without detailed information about the actual error

Comment: As already mentioned, get some logging in place to help identify what is throwing up. One item that might be doing it is the clock skew - we set our tokens to be valid from 10 minutes earlier than the current time (to cover anyone's PC's being bizarrely way out of time); it could be as simple as the token isn't valid 'yet' due to time differences. (Side note: also check that the expiry is handled as UTC time under the hood (it probably is)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Krenom answered in the comments

Set ClockSkew to at least 5 min before NOW due to minor differences in time of client/server. The default ClockSkew value is 5 minutes.

```
ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300)
```